# Rewrite rule works perfect, but I don't want to rewrite www

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, web-applications, url-rewriting

I have this rewrite rule which rewrite demo.mydomain.com to mydomain.com/myform.aspx?url=demo.

```
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="domain redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
  <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.+)\.mydomain\.com$" />
  </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="{REQUEST_URI}/myform.aspx?url={C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
 </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

My problem is that http://www.mydomain.com is rewrited too. How can I exclude www in my rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^(www)](.+)\.mydomain\.com$" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please explain? Do you mean change my match url to that? I tried, but then everything was linked to www.mydomain.com.

Comment: Ahh I read that wrong and added the regex to the wrong line. Updated.

Comment: Thanks, but much closer. Do I need to change this to get right value into ={C:1}" ="{REQUEST_URI}/myform.aspx?url={C:1}"

Comment: When I test the rule in IIS on "test.mydomain.com", c:1 Returns "est"

Comment: I solved it With this dirty trick: ^([^(www)])(.+)\.crmcatch\.com$ and then  ="{REQUEST_URI}/myform.aspx?url={C:1}{C:2}""